# React component that takes state variable as a parameter not rendering on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a React component that makes an AJAX call, sets a state variable and then passes that state variable into a component.

**Main component:**

```
export default function MyView({ assetId }) {
   const [asset, setAsset] = useState();
   const [beanstalk, setBeanstalk] = useState();
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

   useEffect(() => {
      loadAsset();
   }, []);

   const loadAsset = async () => {
        const _asset = await findAssetById(assetId);
        setLoading(false);
        if(_asset) {
            setAsset(_asset);
            await loadBeanstalk(_asset.id);
        }
    };

    const loadBeanstalk = async (assetId) => {
        const _beanstalk = await getBeanstalkFromDB(assetId);
        setBeanstalk(_beanstalk);
    };

   return (
      { loading ? (
         <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
         <h3>{asset.name}</h3>
         <ChildComponent beanstalk={beanstalk} />
      )}
   )
}
```

**Child component:**

```
export default function ChildComponent({ beanstalk }) {
   const [loadbalancer, setLoadbalancer] = useState([]);
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Beanstalk will print as undefined here:");
      console.log(beanstalk);
      getLoadbalancer();
   }, []);

   const getLoadbalancer = async () => {
      if(beanstalk) {
         const _loadbalancer = await getLoadbalancer(beanstalk);
         setLoading(false);
         setLoadbalancer(_loadbalancer);
      }
   }

   return (
      { loading ? (
         <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
         <h3>{loadbalancer.name}</h3>
      )}
   )
}
```

My understanding is that the main component renders when state changes, so when I call `setBeanstalk(_beanstalk)` it should re-render with the `beanstalk` state variable set... so why does ChildComponent always render the Beanstalk as null when I know it's being returned from the database? I know it has something to do with the order of rendering.

Comment: Your effect hook in the child component is only going to run once, maybe try attaching that effect to `beanstalk` instead , e.g. `useEffect(..., [ beanstalk ])`

Comment: That or move setLoading into whereyou setBeanstalk()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue seems to be one of order of operations. What you can try to do is one of the following:

Move your `setLoading(false)` call into `loadBeanstalk()` so that your `ChildComponent` only renders once you have fully loaded the stuff.

```
const loadAsset = async () => {
    const _asset = await findAssetById(assetId);
    if(_asset) {
        setAsset(_asset);
        await loadBeanstalk(_asset.id);
    } else {
        setLoading(false);
    }
};

const loadBeanstalk = async (assetId) => {
    const _beanstalk = await getBeanstalkFromDB(assetId);
    setBeanstalk(_beanstalk);
    setLoading(false);
};
```

Attach `beanstalk` to your `useEffect` hook in `ChildComponent`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Beanstalk will print as undefined here:");
  console.log(beanstalk);
  getLoadbalancer();
}, [ beanstalk ]);
```

Comment: I take my last comment back - it is now working. In fact, a typo (mixing up `asset` and `_asset`) may have been my problem all along. Thanks for the help and have a +1 and a tick.